# Get selected option value from html select with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

See the below list of options, i am trying  to get value of option which is selected.

```
<select>
  <option {class='test'} value="volvo" selected='selected'>Volvo</option>
  <option {class='test'} value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option {class='test'} value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option {class='test'}value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

in the above example i need to get volvo as the matched string. there may or may not have any class parameter.
That's if option string is

```
<option {class='test'} value="volvo" selected='selected'>Volvo</option>
```

or

```
 <option value="volvo" selected='selected'>Volvo</option>
```

Regular expression should return volvo.
That's a regular expression suitable for all cases.

I tried with

```
preg_match_all('/<option\sclass="[^"]*"\svalue="([^"]*)">([^>]*)<\/option>/', $string, $matches);`
```

But that didn't return value of the selected item. Please help.

Comment: See if it works for you and I will put as an answer: http://regexr.com?37uqi

Comment: Did not saw that you need only the selected, so it should be `(.*)(value=")([^"]*)(.*)(selected)(.*)` for `$3`

Comment: why parsing html/xml with regex? what if the `<option` tag was broken into multi-lines?  I can understand if someone want to get some text temporarily, and use regex for a dirty and quick. e.g. in shell get something by curl/wget, and do a grep.  But If you write an application, this kind of thing should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$re = '/^.*\<option.*value=(?:\'|")([a-z]*)(?:\'|").*(?=selected=(?:\'|")selected(?:\'|")).*$/m';

$str = '<select>\n  <option {class=\'test\'} value="volvo" selected=\'selected\'>Volvo</option>\n  <option {class=\'test\'} value="saab">Saab</option>\n  <option {class=\'test\'} value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>\n  <option {class=\'test\'} value="audi">Audi</option>\n</select> '; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($matches);
```

I changed *the logic of* the expression from this:

```
/<option\sclass="[^"]*"\svalue="([^"]*)">([^>]*)<\/option>/
```

to this:

```
/^.*\<option.*value=(?:\'|")([a-z]*)(?:\'|").*(?=selected=(?:\'|")selected(?:\'|")).*$/m
```

and worked fine. See the [regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/qN8rU7)

However I **really** don't recommend regex for parsing html.
I think you should take a look into other ways to accomplish your task, eg. [how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)